Borromean rings on $\Bbb{RP}^2$ and octonions
If I draw a trefoil knot on a projective plane and draw a circle around it touching the three outer parts of the curve. I can view this as a division of the projective plane in 8 triangles, viewed as a graph with 6 vertices. They form an octaeder.
Label the triangle in the middle with $(ij)k$ and the three outer triangles $i$, $j$ and $k$. Label the three remaining triangles except the 'outer circle' triangle $ij$, $jk$ and $ki$ depending on between which two outer triangles they are. Label the 'outer circle' triangle with $1$.
Now view octonion multiplication as generated by anticommuting square roots of $-1$: $i$, $j$ and $k$. For any triple of labels containing an even number of $i$'s, $j$'s and $k$'s, the octonion multiplication of the triple is $\pm 1$. This is the well-known octonion fano cube also shown on wikipedia, where the cube vertices are the midpoints of the triangles of the octaeder.
Equivalently one can look only at a drawing of the borromean rings on a projective plane, label the rings with $i$, $j$ and $k$ and their intersections with their multiplication as above. In this case the 'circle' around appears automatically.
My question: is it probable that some connection can be made between octonions and the trefoil knot or the borromean rings using this correspondence? I'm unfortunately not too well versed in knot theory.

Note: it may be that I mean $\Bbb{CP}^1$ instead of $\Bbb{RP}^2$

What does it mean to draw a trefoil on a projective plane?  And please tell us if that means $\mathbb CP^1$ or $\mathbb RP^2$.

Maybe you meant CP^2 or RP^2.

The drawing means projection on the 2D plane with the smallest number of crossings. I didn't mean $\Bbb CP^2$. The result appears to apply to both $\Bbb CP^1$ and $\Bbb RP^2$

Without pictures this question is very vague. Note that there are standard conventions for drawing on the real projective plane.

I will probably update the question after having read myself into the topic a little
